# Clipping only overlapping datasets using Iterator function in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, clip, feature-class, iterator

I've create a geodatabase with about 100 feature classes for my home province.

I want to be able to specify a project extent and clip the feature classes to that extent and save into a new geodatabase.

I managed to do this in ModelBuilder using an iterator function with one problem, a new feature class is made regardless of whether there are any overlapping features with my study area.

Does anyone know what I could do to avoid this problem? 
In other words how do I export a feature class only where there is an overlapping feature?

Comment: You might consider using getCount and branch http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/06/06/modelbuilderifthenelse1/  or much better - convert model to python script and invest some time in learning python.  You won't regret it. The task you are talking about is piece of cake for arcpy

Comment: Adding to what @FelixIP said, you could get your iterator to write into the in_memory workspace, then count the number of features in the in_memory workspace.  If the count is >0, save to feature class and then delete the in_memory workspace.  If the feature count is 0, then just delete the in_memory workspace.

Comment: Yes, python in on my list of things to do.